# Updating schema with nested type doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

When I create a new index with schema containing this section, it works: - of course, the document has some other fields, this question is about imagesInfo section:

```json
{
    "document": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "imagesInfo": {
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "url": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "crawlingStatus": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "reason": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "http_code": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I update the document schema with the json defined below, it doesn't, even if I retrieve the schema, they are identical:

```json
{
    "document": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "imagesInfo ": {
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "url": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "crawlingStatus": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "reason": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "http_code": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Command to update mapping

```json
curl -X PUT  -d '{
    "document": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "imagesInfo": {
                "properties": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "url": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "crawlingStatus": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "reason": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "http_code": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}' 'http://localhst:9200/indexName/_mapping/document'
```

Any idea?
I suspect updating schema with nested types involves other things, but dunno what.

I tried also to set include_in_parent = true, but without success

Comment: I don't see any difference between the two mappings

Comment: I agree. but a query like

``` lang-json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "imagesInfo.content"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tags_name_terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "imagesInfo.content.reason"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```
works only for new indexes, but not for existing indexes, updated with new fields.

Comment: So, when I update schema with nested type, aggregations don't work. Any idea?

Comment: It depends on how you update. Can you show exactly the commands you're executing, that would help.

Comment: Added above, in the description: curl...

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: The body should only contain the `properties` section, nothing around it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point

Comment: remove `document` and `dynamic`, `properties` should be the top-level section

Comment: but what about the endpoint? should end with `document` or with `_mapping`?

Comment: the endpoint is fine

Comment: Nope, I can't make it.

Comment: What error do you get? What version of ES do you have?

Comment: I am using `ES 5.1 and 5.5`. Basically, I don't get any error, but when I try to retrieve data from an index with schema updated with nested types, I receive `empty result`,

Comment: Are you trying to change the mapping after the fact? i.e. after having ingested some data? if yes, then it is not allowed, you need to reindex your data into another index with the nested mapping.